# Getting TypeError: props.search is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
TypeError: props.search is not a function
```

I'm very new to React and I'm trying to create a 'filter' button, on click it should show a popup with filter element fields. Out of all the fields, only one is a required field - ReqTitle. After populating ReqTitle, when I click on 'search' button, it throws an error - props.search is not a function

Parent code snippet:

```
<React.Fragment>
          <Button 
                  edge="end"
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary" {...bindTrigger(popupState)}>
                  ☰ Filter 
          </Button>
          <Menu {...bindMenu(popupState)}>
           <Filters >  </Filters>
          </Menu>
</React.Fragment>
```

Child Code snippet:

```
  function data() {
    if (!Object.values(inputErrors).some(x => x)) {
      if (!Object.values(filterValues).some((x) => (x && !Array.isArray(x)) || (x && x.length > 0))) {
        setFieldRequired(true);
      } 
      else if ((filterValues.startDate && !filterValues.endDate) || (!filterValues.startDate && filterValues.endDate)) {
        setNeedBothDates(true);
      }
      else {
        props.search(filterValues);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have also appended at the end (and wonder if this is causing the issue) :

```
Filters.propTypes = {
  search: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Function declaration:

```
export default function Filters(props) {
  const [filterValues, setFilterValues] = useState({
    sDate: null,
    eDate: null,
    ReqTitle: "",
    eTitle: "",
    channels: [],
    countries: [],
    genres: []
  });
```

I'm also seeing a warning which states : *The prop `search` is marked as required in `Filters`, but its value is `undefined`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any prop by the name `search` to `<Filters />` component. Also, you have added prop type validation to your component which in essence means that the component `Filters` requires a mandatory `search` prop. Pass it like

```js
<Filters
   search = {/*value to be passed*/}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks much for the direction! It worked.